# using member name in macro definition

Tags: c, linux-kernel, macros

I'm developing a user-space application that uses linux/list.h as one of the headers.
However, i ran into a problem when I uses this macro definition "list_for_each_entry" from list.h in my own application:

```
#define list_for_each_entry(pos, head, member)              \
for (pos = list_first_entry(head, typeof(*pos), member);    \
     &pos->member != (head);                    \
     pos = list_next_entry(pos, member))

static void *slob_alloc(size_t size){
  struct slob_page *sp;
  struct list_head *slob_list;

  list_for_each_entry(sp, slob_list, list) {  //The location where error is reported.
  //Something else ...
  }
}
```

The definitions of slob_page is as below:

```
struct slob_page {
union {
    struct {
        slob_t *free;       
        struct list_head list;  /* the member accessed by that macro expansion */
    };
    struct page page;
};
```

};

The compiler raised an error "error: use of undeclared identifier 'list';". Seems like it failed to recognize list as the member name.

How could i resolve this?

Comment: The macro uses *2* other macros, namel `list_first_entry` and `list_next_entry`. Are you sure you did use their definitions too?!

Comment: the arguments or text replacements are automatically populated down along with the expansion, right?

Comment: Yes... provided that the macro definitions are there.

Comment: yeah i didn't touch the list.h

Comment: preprocess your program with `gcc -E` and compile this preprocessed output and see the line that errors

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler doesn't know what the member you used in the struct.
you need to point your member like this:

```
"sp->"union data"->list
```

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended that you use macro to define such a complicated thing. Use function instead will be better.